# Given only a pointer to a node to be deleted in a singly linked list, how do you delete it?

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, linked-list

Example: If a linkedlist list contains 10->20->30->40, and 2nd node has to be deleted then  the output should be 10->30->40

This question is attributed to Geeksforgeeks. Looking for code-review, optimizations and best-practices.

```
    class Nodde<T> {
        Nodde<T> next; 
        T item;

        Nodde(T item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    class LinkedList<T> {

        private Nodde<T> first;
        private Nodde<T> last;

        public LinkedList(Nodde<T> first) {
            this.first = first;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hashCode = 1;
            for (Nodde x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
                hashCode = 31*hashCode + (x == null ? 0 : x.hashCode());
            return hashCode;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {

            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            LinkedList<T> other = (LinkedList<T>) obj;
            Nodde<T> currentListNode = first; 
            Nodde<T> otherListNode =  other.first;

            while (currentListNode != null && otherListNode != null) {

                if (currentListNode.item != otherListNode.item) {
                    System.out.println(currentListNode.item);
                    return false;
                }
                currentListNode = currentListNode.next;
                otherListNode = otherListNode.next;
            }

            return currentListNode == null && otherListNode == null;
        }
    }

    public final class DeletePtr<T> {

        public static <T> void delete(Nodde<T> ptr) {

            if (ptr == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The pointer cannot be null.");
            }

            if (ptr.next == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The last node cannot be deleted.");
            }

            ptr.item = ptr.next.item;
            ptr.next = ptr.next.next;
        }
    }


public class DeletePtrTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Nodde<Integer> node1 = new Nodde<Integer>(10);
        Nodde<Integer> node2 = new Nodde<Integer>(20);
        Nodde<Integer> node3 = new Nodde<Integer>(30);
        Nodde<Integer> node4 = new Nodde<Integer>(40);
        Nodde<Integer> node5 = new Nodde<Integer>(50);

        node1.next = node2;
        node2.next = node3;
        node3.next = node4;
        node4.next = node5;

        DeletePtr.delete(node3);

        LinkedList<Integer> llActual = new LinkedList<Integer>(node1);

        Nodde<Integer> nodeExpected1 = new Nodde<Integer>(10);
        Nodde<Integer> nodeExpected2 = new Nodde<Integer>(20);
        Nodde<Integer> nodeExpected3 = new Nodde<Integer>(40);
        Nodde<Integer> nodeExpected4 = new Nodde<Integer>(50);

        nodeExpected1.next = nodeExpected2;
        nodeExpected2.next = nodeExpected3;
        nodeExpected3.next = nodeExpected4;


        LinkedList<Integer> llExpected = new LinkedList<Integer>(nodeExpected1);
        assertEquals(llActual, llExpected);
    }


    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Nodde<Integer> node1 = new Nodde<Integer>(10);
        Nodde<Integer> node2 = new Nodde<Integer>(20);
        Nodde<Integer> node3 = new Nodde<Integer>(30);
        Nodde<Integer> node4 = new Nodde<Integer>(40);
        Nodde<Integer> node5 = new Nodde<Integer>(50);

        node1.next = node2;
        node2.next = node3;
        node3.next = node4;
        node4.next = node5;

        DeletePtr.delete(node4);

        LinkedList<Integer> llActual = new LinkedList<Integer>(node1);

        Nodde<Integer> nodeExpected1 = new Nodde<Integer>(10);
        Nodde<Integer> nodeExpected2 = new Nodde<Integer>(20);
        Nodde<Integer> nodeExpected3 = new Nodde<Integer>(30);
        Nodde<Integer> nodeExpected4 = new Nodde<Integer>(50);

        nodeExpected1.next = nodeExpected2;
        nodeExpected2.next = nodeExpected3;
        nodeExpected3.next = nodeExpected4;


        LinkedList<Integer> llExpected = new LinkedList<Integer>(nodeExpected1);
        assertEquals(llActual, llExpected);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Nodde` instead of `Node`? Intentional typo???

Comment: I think it's to prevent namespace collisions, but that's not a good excuse. Incoming review...

Comment: Perhaps you should compare elements with `Equals` instead of `==` in your overridden `Equals` method.

Comment: You've misunderstood the challenge. You are *only* given a point to the node to be deleted. In your code you also have pointers to the start and end of the linked list. The point of the challenge is to delete the node without access to either of those.

Comment: @200_success, this looks to me like the textbook example of what I meant when I created the reinventing-the-wheel tag.

Comment: I mentioned this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17010929#17010929). I hope we can come to a conclusion as what to do with the question.

Comment: I can't join chat where I am right now, but this clearly seems to be a beginner-intermediate level programming challenge.  Telling the OP to use Java's library is like asking them to skip their data structures and algorithms courses.  There is so much they can learn by thinking about and implementing a linked list, even if it's not something you would push into production-level code.

Comment: What was the programming challenge question — [this one](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-a-given-node-in-linked-list-under-given-constraints/)? If so, the inputs, and therefore the solution, should be quite different.

Comment: @Ryan the issue is that changing the question now might seriously overhaul the answers, which is pretty much a no-no. You yourself have posted a pretty lengthy answer - changing the question to point to the question would make it be broken code (it does not do what it should do), and changing the question AND code invalidates the answers.

Comment: @Pimgd I agree.  If the question is representative of the challenge 200_success linked it is a very different question indeed(though simplified somewhat by only having to deal with `int` instead of generics in the node!)

Comment: @Pimgd You're right, clarifying the question now would just make an even bigger mess. I've just reopened it — and downvoted.

Answer (score 17):

I had tagged your question [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel), because you're recreating a `LinkedList`, and Java already has one. @200_success has removed this tag for some reason, allowing me to post this answer:

**Use Java's built-in LinkedList.**

There's no reason for you to be writing your own implementation. Using Java's own `LinkedList` (full classified name: `java.util.LinkedList`), you can use `removeAt(index)` to remove a node. If you only have a reference to an object that is contained in the list, you can use `remove(Object)`.

As it stands right now, you expose your nodes to the user of your class. You make THEM manage the LinkedList, whereas the LinkedList itself is nothing but a wrapper. If the user messes up and accidentally points the last node to another node, then makes a clone and compares them with `equals` or `==`, **the program will get into an infinite loop**. If someone inserts a LinkedList which has the last node point to another node into something like a `HashMap`, **the program will get into an infinite loop**.

Searching for an element in the list requires the user to built their own implementation of a search function. In fact, doing anything with the list (other than removing an element) requires the user to get their hands dirty.

But lets say I wanted to use this LinkedList for a valid purpose.
I can't even remove the last node from the LinkedList. That could significantly limit my options.

Actually, removing itself is rather dirty because you've called it `delete`. This gives me certain assumptions - namely, that the object won't exist anymore after I have called the function.
I call `delete(Node)` and surprise surprise... the node still exists! Except it has different values now. This means you're altering the objects I'm holding in my hands. You're even altering the objects you're holding in your own hands - in the `first` and `last` fields.

There's another bug related to that: When I make a list of 2 Nodes, and I remove the first one, you end up having a LinkedList that contains 1 node... double! **And if I were to add another node with a different item in it, `last` wouldn't even point to the proper node!**

When you combine all these reasons, you should see that it is a bad idea to reinvent the wheel. Just use Java's `LinkedList` and the methods they provide. That way you don't have as much bugs, you don't force the user to make their hands dirty, you don't have to test whether your list works, and you give your user more freedom in how they can use the list.

Comment: I was going to downvote this (for saying "just use `LinkedList`" on what looks like a data structures assignment or challenge) then I remembered I was on codereview.

Comment: There are occasionally reasons to reimplement singly linked lists.  The best case that I see is for tail sharing (which sometimes tends to suggest immutability, too).  This question doesn't seem to use that functionality, though, so I think this advise of "just use Java's list" makes sense here.

Comment: I have nothing against building your own implementation of LinkedList. ... but if you are gonna do it, then you need to be really sure that doing it yourself is the best course of action.

Comment: `remove(Object)` and `removeAt(int)` are not really the same as deleting a node given a pointer to it.  A better analogy would be `ListIterator.remove()`.

Comment: -1 for writing a several paragraph post telling them to use LinkedList when the OP was doing a coding exercise

Comment: @WinstonEwert I tagged the question [tag:reinventing-the-wheel]. The tag was removed as it didn't apply. Thus, my answer is valid and the comment "coding exercise" is INVALID. In the event that [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] DOES apply, you're right, and my answer should remove the notion about using the built-in linked list (instead placing more emphasis on the bugs in the implementation).

Comment: My bad, please edit your post so I can remove my downvote.

Answer (score 8):

Here:

```
        for (Nodde x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
            hashCode = 31*hashCode + (x == null ? 0 : x.hashCode());
```

inside the loop you know that `x!=null` so no need for ternary operator.

Answer (score 3):

### `Nodde`

For starters, as others have mentioned it seems odd to have your node named `Nodde`.  If you have a valid reason for this, that's great, but it should probably be renamed as `Node`.  As Pimgd noted in their comment, this might be indicative of namespace collisions.  In Java, we avoid namespace collisions through `packages`.  I suggest, even for simple projects like this, to use packages.  I have a `test` project and its package is `com.me.testing`.

Also, its `Node<T>` should be nested. See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for a guideline on doing that in Java.  Doing this will completely close out the outside world from knowing what you're doing underneath, which is a good thing.  This `hides the implementation`.

Additionally, you should make the constituent pieces of the node `private`.  Exposing the underlying implementation is almost always a bad code smell and poor practice.  In this case, it probably makes sense to have setters and getters for both `next` and `item`, which makes `private` kind of moot anyway, but it's good to get into the habit of hiding class members, as well as **always** providing the `access modifiers` (public, protected, private, etc).  Even if your intended access level is the same as the language's default, it's a good thing to explicitly state, because it tells your future self that you thought about, and came to the conclusion, that your access modifier should be `public` or `private`, etc.

### Outside of `LinkedList`; `DeletePtr`

There's some red flags in `DeletePtr`.  The first is that it exists at all (no offense intended here!).  The problem is that `DeletePtr` is making important decisions about another class - `LinkedList` - and it *should not* be able to make those decisions.  This creates a very high coupling between the two classes, when in fact the 'delete' routine should just be part of `LinkedList`.  `LinkedList` is the owner of the data structure, and therefore should have control over adding or removing nodes.

Also, carrying around the idea of "pointer" is something Java discourages.  As Pimgd noted, `delete` has other connotations to it and `remove` is perhaps a better word for what you're doing (well, it *is* used by Java's LinkedList, after all).

Another concern is not being able to delete the last node.  If I have the list 10->20->30->40 and ask for the 40 to be removed, should it not become 10->20->30?  Your removal of a node is a bit flawed for this reason, but we can fix that soon...

### `LinkedList`

First of all: adding nodes.  Currently, you let your users of the `LinkedList` add nodes however they see fit.  This is bad, because your user is a monkey at a keyboard and will do stupid things.  (This is true even if the only user of your code is you.  Trust no one!)  To prevent them from sticking their hands where they don't belong, we can add an `add` method to `LinkedList`, like so:

```
public void add(T item) {
    if (null != item) {
        if (null == first){
            first = new Node<T>(item);
        }
        else if (null == last) {
            last = new Node<T>(item);
            first.setNext(last);
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> newLast = new Node<T>(item);
            last.setNext(newLast);
            last = newLast;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't expose `Node` to the user.  Instead, the user can add an item of type `T`.

Also, we can move the functionality of `DeletePtr` into `LinkedList`.  We'll call it `remove`.  This is entirely new code that doesn't reflect what `DeletePtr` was doing.

```
public void remove(T item) {
    if (item == first.getItem()) {
        first = first.getNext();
    }

    Node<T> curr = first;
    while (null != curr) {
        if(curr.getNext() != null 
        && curr.getNext().getItem() == item) { // Check the *next* node
            curr.setNext(curr.getNext().getNext());
        }

        curr = curr.getNext();
    }

    if (null == first) {
        last = null;
    }
}
```

That function may look confusing, but it will be better if you can draw out what it's doing on paper.  A few notes:

- You can remove both the first and last nodes.
- No exceptions.  Exceptions should only occur when exceptionally bad things happen.  Is attempting to add `null` to a list exceptional?  Maybe, but most likely not.  Appending `null` onto a list should have no effect on the list.
- It checks `references`.  Again, Java eschews the idea of `pointers`.  An object is 'deleted' or 'freed' when it is no longer being *referenced*.
- The loop is a typical linked-list loop, but slightly modified because it's looking one node ahead.  When the next node is the node we want to 'remove' we simply assign the current node's `next` to the next node's `next`.  In C/C++ this would leave an object hanging in memory, and be called a memory leak.  In Java, an object is automatically released by the garbage collector when it is no longer being referenced anywhere else (a bit of a simplification, but you can read up on the GC elsewhere for more detail).  It's still a potential vector for memory leaks.

### Equality

For checking equality, there are improvements to be made.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628718/java-type-safety-generics-equals) is a good question that explains what's going on.  How you check for equality is up to you, but if you're able to do it in a way that's agnostic to the type of the generics, all the better.

### Constructor

The constructor that takes an item is a bit flawed.  By assigning the item to first and last, you're essentially saying that there are now two values in the list.  However, first doesn't point to last yet, so only the first one will be seen if you traverse the list.  It would be best to simply assign last to null until you have something better to put there(the second node).  For the code below, I simply removed that constructor.

### Conclusion

This isn't a perfect LinkedList, obviously, but it's a step in the right direction.  As Pimgd said, if you ever have the choice between writing your own version of something and using a tested and vetted library, choose the library.  Java's LinkedList has been written, analyzed, studied, and benchmarked by very smart people whose goal was to optimize the functionality therein.  Unless you can pinpoint an area where your implementation needs to be faster, it's best to use a library's version.  My 1.5 hours of writing code + explaining it is not bullet proof, and certainly nowhere near as robust as the built in library's code.

The full class, without `hashCode` and `equals` (which I didn't touch):

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
    static class Node<T> {
        private Node<T> next; 
        private T item;

        public Node(T item) {
            this.item = item;
        }

        public T getItem() {
            return item;
        }

        public Node<T> getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node<T> node){
            next = node;
        }
    }

    private Node<T> first;
    private Node<T> last;

    public LinkedList(){
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }

    public void add(T item) {
        if (null != item) {
            if (null == first){
                first = new Node<T>(item);
            }
            else if (null == last) {
                last = new Node<T>(item);
                first.setNext(last);
            }
            else
            {
                Node<T> newLast = new Node<T>(item);
                last.setNext(newLast);
                last = newLast;
            }
        }
    }

    public void remove(T item) {
        if (item == first.getItem()) {
            first = first.getNext();
        }

        Node<T> curr = first;
        while (null != curr) {
            if(curr.getNext() != null && curr.getNext().getItem() == item) {
                curr.setNext(curr.getNext().getNext());
            }

            curr = curr.getNext();
        }

        if (null == first) {
            last = null;
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: "because your user is a monkey at a keyboard and will do stupid things" This warrants a second upvote. Good review.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the slightly odd class name `Nodde` (nothing wrong), one suggestion I can make is to use some sort of a builder (or "fluent"?) pattern to construct your linked lists... Possibly along the lines of:

```
<T> LinkedList<T> createList(T... elements) {
    // assume elements is validated
    Nodde<T> lastNode = new Nodde<>(elements[elements.length - 1]);
    for (int i = elements.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        Nodde<T> currentNode = new Nodde<>(elements[i]);
        currentNode.next = lastNode;
        lastNode = currentNode;
    }
    return new LinkedList<T>(currentNode);
}
```

For constructing the expected linked list.